# Deploy Django project with MSSQL DB in Local Server

Tags: django, deployment, web-deployment

I am new in Django and this will be my very FIRST Times web deploying. So I am trying to deploy my project to the local server and My project stack is Django with MSSQL so obviously I will need Window.

I was read the documentation and I think I will need WSGI and As the documentation say to deploy with `gunicron` or uWSGI but both are supported for Unix and not for window. So How can I start this one? This will be the first question.

I would like to know whether I am doing is correct or not.

Now I copy my project to the local server and when I try to run my project like `python manage.py runserver` it asks me to install Django and other but I thought this environment is working at well my computer and all of the needed application is already installed in the environment. So I still need to install all of my needed apps like Django to this environment again?

If u have any tutorial or can guide me to some useful site, I will be very very appreciated.

Anything u want to know further, Just let me know.

Thanks.